# How to transform/update one flow depending on another flow?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-flow

I have a two flows. One is a list of products updated by network calls and the second flow is a list of products read from a local SQLite database (using Room).

#### Storefront flow

```kotlin
Get all products  --- Network ---\
Search products   --- Network ------- List<Products> ---> data class Cart ---> Flow<List<Product>>
Filter products   --- Network ---/
```

#### Cart flow

```kotlin
Load Cart from SQLite --- Room ------ Flow ---> Flow<List<Product>>
```

The `List<Product>` read from SQLite will have the latest quantity, read using a flow. And I would like this quantity to be reflected to the `List<Product>` used in the `Storefront`.

**Question**

1. How to I transform the storefront flow to have the latest quantity in accordance with the product and quantity in the cart.

Comment: Take a look at this. Might be the answer to your task: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57693392/merging-kotlin-flows

Comment: I'd recommend stepping back and looking at this differently and try to rearchitect your solution to include a single source of truth. Right now you've got data coming from two places and you're planning on merging them.  https://medium.com/@sina.rahimi/single-source-of-truth-with-mvvm-retrofit2-livedata-rxjava-and-room-in-repository-pattern-f5304f39175

Comment: You can try using combine()